# Repeat the contents of the SELECTED cell in another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't think this is possible, but I'm often pleasantly surprised by some creative solutions people come up with :)

In Excel (I'm using 365), is there a way to display the contents of the currently selected cell in another cell?

So if I click on A1 containing "blue", then "blue" is shown in (for example) G3, but the moment I click on C5 containing "Gordon", then G3 changes to "Gordon".  And so on.

Why?  I'm working in a data-dense sheet and often I'm trying to see what's in the cell I'm looking at and I'd just like a larger merged cell that shows me the contents in full (or as full as the larger cell will allow).  Maybe think of it sort of like a magnifying glass?

It would mostly be just a quick and dirty and TEMPORARY helper while I'm working with the data and before I'm concerning myself with formatting.

Note: I'm locked out of VB on this system, so that isn't an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to achieve such result without VBA because selecting a cell does not trigger recalculation and without recalculation the result will not change.
Generally you can use a formula:

```
=CELL("contents")
```

This formula shows the contents of the last edited cell or the cell selected at the time the worksheet was calculated. So to make it work you should not only select a cell but additionally e.g. press `F9` to calculate the workbbook.
[image: Selection]

Comment: This seems be a peculiar one, *"Omitting the reference argument does not reliably produce information about a specific cell"* - Ref: https://www.google.com/search?q=Excelv+CELL+function  (notably: LibreOffice Calc does not accept the reference as "optional")

Comment: My answer concerns Microsoft Excel.  "If omitted, the information specified in the info_type argument is returned for cell selected at the time of calculation. If the reference argument is a range of cells, the CELL function returns the information for active cell in the selected range." from Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf

Comment: See, I knew someone would come up with something simple and elegant :)  Or, at least, as elegant as possible given no VBA.  Your answer is functional for my needs.  Thank you.